# Is it posible BLOCK windows APPS with a script?

Tags: windows, python

Is it possible to create a script to block certain windows apps in certain periods of time?

[Something like that in android (when I click on the app, I'm not able of opening it):](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QXYnH.jpg)

The purpose of the script would be to block certain apps like games or social media while working to be more productive.

Could that be done in windows? I would like to do it with python but if another language is the appropriate one, I don't mind.

I would be really helpful if someone could help me!
Also, if more info is needed, just tell and I will post it.

Answer (score 2):

Ask yourself: What is your company's acceptable use policy?

If your computers are considered business tools rather than employee perks perhaps users should not be given local administrative rights in the first place. This would immediately make it harder to install most software. Add [AppLocker](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/5211.how-to-configure-applocker-group-policy-to-prevent-software-from-running.aspx) group policies to this, and you will have eliminated the problem for most regular users.

Answer (score 0):

You could make a script/daemon that is constantly looking for certain processes and closes them. It's not pretty, it's not great, but you can probably do it in 30 minutes.

You can use the package wmi to fetch the processes and then kill those who match your criteria.